# Text not being saved to String variable

Tags: java, android, string, http, url

I have been trying to get an app to work that allows me to read from a URL and then use the text that I get from the URL for other purposes in the app.

The problem I'm having is that the text isn't being "saved".

I know for a fact that my #getText method works because I ran a basic command line application in IntelliJ:

```
String textFromUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {
textFromUrl = Vars.getEngUrlText();
System.out.println(textFromUrl);
}
```

and the result was it printing the exact text it should. And this was written inside of the main activity's class in my Android project, I just ran the main method as a normal Java application instead of running the actual apk from my USB device.

Now, I try to do the same in the Android device by doing
In Vars class:

```
String textFromUrl;
```

In #onCreate of the first activity:

```
Vars.textFromUrl = Vars.getEngUrlText();

TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletext);
tx.setText(Vars.textFromUrl);
```

and it just displays blank, no text, no nothing. Rest of the layout is fine though, everything else shows and no errors. I'm assuming the value of textFromUrl is null and I don't know why.

Yes I do have the proper permissions to access the web in my AndroidManifest because I'm using a WebView and it works fine. I've even tried running threads that give it some time to wait (about 5 seconds) before changing the text and it still won't work.

What's going on?

## getText and #getEngUrlText below.

getEngUrlText calls getText:

```
public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {

        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);

        in.close();



        return response.toString();
    }

public static String getEngUrlText() {
        try {
            textFromUrl = getText("url that is supposed to be here removed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return textFromUrl;
    }
```

Comment: what's the point of `Vars.textFromUrl = Vars.getEngUrlText();` when you can just do `tx.setText(Vars.getEngUrlText())`

Comment: Post your `getEngUrlText()` method. My hunch is that it's asynchronous, so you end up calling `setText` before `textFromUrl` gets set a value.

Comment: Eh no point really but I guess I could use it for caching later. Anyways, it made no difference. But I once again tested it by sticking a main method in the Vars class and using the getEngUrlText method and it printed the text out as normal.

Comment: Edited in the getEngUrlText() method to OP.

Comment: Fixed this by targeting a lower SDK. Apparently I didn't see a NetworkOnMainThreadException that the logcat was displaying because I was only looking for errors and not all warnings and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by targetting a lower SDK. Apparently I didn't see a NetworkOnMainThreadException that the logcat was displaying because I was only looking for errors and not all warnings and such.